# fill content selector in table

Tags: css, angular

How to fill content my selector in Angular2?
template:

```
<table id="gboard"  >
  <tr *ngFor="let x of gameBoard">
    <td *ngFor="let field of x">
       <game-field [field]="field" (click)="handleClick(field)" [class.cross]="field.player==0"></game-field>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

component def:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'game-field',
template: ' test',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

and css:

```
table, th, td, game-field { 
  border: 1px solid black;
   height: 50px;
}
td,game-field{
  width: 50px;
}
.cross{
  width: 45px;
height: 45px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 35%, #d00 35%, #d00 65%,  transparent 65%),
  linear-gradient(to right, transparent 35%, #d00 35%, #d00 65%, transparent 65%);
}
.circle{
  border-radius: 50%;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

[image: see effect]

as you can see class selector fill only text area - why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: try adding `game-field { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
game-field { display: block; }
```

to the components CSS